# Activity Stream using Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activity-streams

I am venturing out to add an activity stream/news feed to my application. My tech stack is primarily Java based (Spring Boot). Are there any Java based open source libraries that can help me get started (ideally something that uses the Activity Stream 2.0 specification).

Answer (score 0):

There are a great lib for you: https://github.com/OpenSocial/activitystreams

Comment: Great thanks I'll take a look at this. Does this support writing to a datastore such as Redis/Cassandra?